# mod_rewrite gives me 404

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I wanna rewrite links like
`index.php?page=entry&id=15&action=edit` to `entry/15/edit`.
This is how my .htaccess looks like now:

```
# Turn the Rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/([^/]*)/?)([^/]*)?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&action=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Gives me 404.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too many parentheses.  You might have a Lisp infection.

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&action=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a really good one page mod_rewrite cheat sheet here: https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/